How to replace empty message?
There is a chart widget. This widget displays text "No visible series" instead of chart when user disable all legend items . I need replace "No visible series" to any text.
To do this i try to add to config the following settings:
  overlays: {
    noData: {
      text: "this is my new text!",
    },
  },

However it doesn't work. Please help me replace this text.
live example is here.
PS: To disable all legend items, you need to click on them all.
This is a config entirely:
{
      title: {
        text: "Browser Usage Statistics",
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: "2009-2019",
      },
      data: getData(),
      overlays: {
        noData: {
          text: "No data to displayzzz",
        },
      },
      series,
      legend,
    };


You can change the translation in two ways.

Via overlay options.
Via locale options.

First solution:
{
  title: {
    text: "Browser Usage Statistics",
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: "2009-2019",
  },
  data: getData(),
  overlays: {
    noVisibleSeries: {
      text: "This is my new text!"
    }
  }
  series,
  legend,
};

Second solution:
{
  title: {
    text: "Browser Usage Statistics",
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: "2009-2019",
  },
  data: getData(),
  locale: {
    localeText: {
      overlayNoVisibleSeries: "This is my new text!",
    },
  },
  series,
  legend,
};


Your approach is correct, however you need to target the noVisibleSeries overlay rather than the noData one.
  overlays: {
     noVisibleSeries: {
      text: "this is my new text!",
    },
  },

See more details at https://charts.ag-grid.com/angular/overlays/.
Alternatively you can use the locale approach suggested here.
